# How do you use the Magento API to add products to a bundle?

Tags: rest, soap, bundle, magento-1.8

I'm developing a system that integrates an existing Django application with a Magento store. I've managed, using [this](https://github.com/openlabs/magento) library, to create bundle-type products, along with attributes and categories as expected. The problem is that I can't find a way, using the SOAP API (either through the aforementioned library or calling the `xmlrpc` methods directly), to add products to a previously created bundle. Calling the `catalog_product.info` method doesn't return anything useful about the bundled objects.

Researching online, I've only found solutions that involve either:

- PHP scripts that use the Magento code base
- Straight-to-database insertion

Neither of these is currently an option for me right now, and I don't think being able to do this by using just the API (either REST or SOAP) isn't an irrealistic expectation to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can export header information about a bundled product, so I assume you can import it back to Magento.  However there does not appear to be a way to import component structure of a bundle. This would be a very complicated interface,